# AngularJs Service with NgResource and custom methods combined

Tags: angularjs, methods, service, factory, ngresource

Is it possible to have a service with custom methods AND the `NgResource` functionality?

Or do I have to create and manage 2 objects throughout the application? One for `$resource` (a factory), another one for other things like keeping values after routing (a .service for example).

I mean, all the examples I read implementing `NgResource` like a service shows a factory object returning only ONE thing, the $resource component. Like this:

```
.factory('User', function($resource){

  return $resource(URL + ':id', {}, {
     edit: {method:'PUT'}
     ....
     ....
  });
```

This is useful and clear. Just call: `User.edit(...);`

What if I need a custom method to do some process, like:

```
User.calculateSomethingAboutTheUser()
```

What if I need to remember the user values after routing? I'm accomplishing this using a service (.service), called `User`, like this in the controller:

```
$scope.user = User;
```

I can't do that with the factory example because it's always returning the `$resource` object.

Answer (score 1):

actually `$http` and it's abstraction `$resource` are just for loading data from server side, it's data layer. and it's better to declare additional service for calculations (store some state and so on) and it will be business logic layer. then you declare some directives which help you to display/get data (eg user input). and it's presentation layer. those directives call methods on your business logic services and BL services call data layer if needed.